# Bypass CAPTHA via user input

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to create a python web-scraper to collect some site data.

However, the target site only will grant access after a single CAPTCHA is fulfilled (a one time event)

I was thinking if it is possible to use a simple web-scraper script (like selenium) to:

1. make a first contact to the target site,
2. get the CAPTCHA img, and display it to the user,
3. **use a user input to ask the CAPTCHA value**,
4. **and send the request back to the site, in order to continue navigation.**

Is it even possible?

Comment: yest it is, have you ever used selenium toolkit?

Comment: Hi there. No, I've never used selenium before, but I'm willing to.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing using python/PyQt4 and JavaScript